# Не могу отправить FormData если файл в форме не прекреплен

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formdata

Ситуация такая. Есть форма:

```
<form id="f-<?php echo ($user) ? "edit" : "add";?>-user" class="two-columns">

            <div class="f-user-avatar include-avatar">
                <?php  echo ($user['avatar']) ? "<img src='/img/avatars/".$user['avatar']."'>" : "<div class='default-av'>hC</div>"; ?>
                <?php  echo ($user['avatar']) ? "<span class='btn btn-outline-secondary' onclick='RemoveAvatar(".$user['id'].");'>Удалить</span>" : "" ?>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Имя сотрудника <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="fau-name" value="<?php echo $user['name']; ?>" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Имя сотрудника"/>
                </div>  
                <label class="form-label">Аватар</label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="custom-file-input" id="avatar" onchange="SetFile('avatar');">

                    <label id="avatarinput" class="custom-file-label" for="avatar"><?php  echo ($user['avatar']) ? $user['avatar'] : "Выберите файл"; ?></label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Должность <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="fau-occupation" value="<?php echo $user['occupation']; ?>" type="text" name="occupation" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Должность"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Контактный телефон <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="fau-phone" value="<?php echo $user['phone']; ?>" type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Контактный телефон"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Пароль</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Установите пароль"/>
                </div>
                <div class="two-columns equal">
                    <div style="margin-right:20px">
                        <label class="form-label">Ломбард</label>
                        <select id="fau-pawnshop" name="pawnshop[]" multiple class="demo-default" placeholder="Выберите ломбард">
                            <?php 
                            $usersPsArray = explode(",", $user['pawnshop']);
                            echo '<option value="all" '.(in_array("all", $usersPsArray) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>Все ломбарды</option>';

                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pawnshops ORDER BY name");
                            while($pawnshops = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo'<option value="'.$pawnshops['id'].'" '.(in_array($pawnshops['id'], $usersPsArray) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$pawnshops['name'].'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <script>
                            $('#fau-pawnshop').selectize();
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Профиль доступа <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <select id="fau-profile" name="profile" class="custom-select">
                            <?php echo ($user) ? "" : "<option selected disabled>Выбрать</option>";?>
                            <?php 
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_profiles ORDER BY name");
                            while($profiles = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo'<option value="'.$profiles['id'].'" '.($user['profile'] == $profiles['id'] ? "selected" : "").'>'.$profiles['name'].'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo ($user) ? "6" : "5";?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>"/>
        </form>
```

В этой форме есть поле:

```
<input type="file" name="avatar" class="custom-file-input" id="avatar" onchange="SetFile('avatar');">
```

Я пытаюсь отправить эту форму через formData. Вот мой js

```
function SaveUser(action){
    var formData = new FormData($("#f-"+action+"-user")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/dbfunctions.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        if(msg==1)
        {
            new Noty({text: '<strong>Ошибка!</strong><br/>Для сохранения информации о сотруднике необходимо заполнить обязательные поля', type: 'error'}).show();

            if($("#fau-name").val()=="")
                $("#fau-name").addClass('error-border');
            if($("#fau-phone").val()=="")
                $("#fau-phone").addClass('error-border');
            if($("#fau-occupation").val()=="")
                $("#fau-occupation").addClass('error-border');
            if($("#fau-profile").val()==null)
                $("#fau-profile").addClass('error-border');
        }
        if(msg==2)
            location.href="/pages/users/employees.php";
    });
}
```

Но я не могу доступиться к functions/dbfunctions.php

Если же я прикреплю в форме, то тогда идет подключение к файлу dbfunctions.php.

Само поле аватар не является обязательным, тут что то с formData, и я не понимаю почему нельзя отправить форму, если файл не выбран. Помогите пожалуйста:(

[image: Скриншот "Сети"]

Добавляю данные, которые отправляются:

[image: Данные]

Обработчик dbfunction.php

```
//Add/Edit users
  if($_POST['type']==5 || $_POST['type']==6)
  {
    echo "here";
}
```

Comment: Собственно а в чем проблема? Что-то не исполняется? Не приходит ответ? \

Comment: ну у меня в js на .done выводится alert(msg), который должен показать "here". Но он не показывает. "here" это для теста, вообще там дальше была php обработка полей.  Если же я в форме файл прикреплю, тогда у меня будет "here"...

Comment: Ну потому что в форме вы не посылаете `enctype`, попробуйте в обработчик добавить блок `else` и вывести там все что угодно, он должен заработать.

Comment: Откуда вызывается SaveUser?

Comment: В функцию SaveUser я попадаю. вызывается из файла employees.php, сама же функция присутствует в футере во всех страницах сайта

Comment: Я не могу понять, неужели через formData можно отправлять только файлы? почему я не могу отправить просто без файла, и как выйти из этой ситуации

Comment: Вы понимаете, что скорее всего дело в серверном скрипте, попробуйте просто что-то там вывести без проверок, скорее всего это будет отображено в `.done`, и дело будет именно в серверном скрипте, а точнее в проверке, ибо скорее всего есть недействительные поля.

Comment: Вот костыль, который решает мою проблему в данный момент. Прикрепляю его в качестве ответа, но я думаю что он не досконален. Как я понимаю через FormData надо отправлять обязательно файл. Если его нет, то почему то не срабатывает. Возможно все же кто то подскажет как сделать правильно без костылей

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант костыля. Пожалуйста представьте более удачный вариант.

В JS файле:

```
if($("#avatar").val())
    {
        var formData = new FormData($("#f-"+action+"-user")[0]);
        var params = {
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/dbfunctions.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var formData = $("#f-"+action+"-user").serialize();
        var params = {
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/dbfunctions.php",
            data: formData,
        }
    }
```

и дальше

```
$.ajax(params).done(function(msg){
```